# How can I get the class-loader sequencing of Tomcat 8 to behave exactly like Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, tomcat

For a Java Web Application:

From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html
the default class-loader sequence for **Tomcat 6** is:

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
2. System class loader classes
3. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
4. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
5. Common class loader classes (annotations, catalina jars etc.)

From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html
the default class-loader sequence for **Tomcat 8** is:

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
2. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
3. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
4. System class loader classes
5. Common class loader classes (annotations, catalina jars etc.)

As you can see, the load order is different.

Now in Tomcat 8 (Context.xml or Server.xml), I can set

```
<Loader delegate="true" />
```

to change the Tomcat 8 class-loader sequence to:

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM
2. System class loader classes
3. Common class loader classes (annotations, catalina jars etc.)
4. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
5. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application

As you can see, this sequence is quite a bit closer to Tomcat 6, though not 100% same.

Is there a way in Tomcat 8 Server to make the class-loader sequence, same as Tomcat 6? Is **delegate="true"** the closest we can get?

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation for tomcat 8.5 class loader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

Under Advanced configuration:

> The Server class loader is only visible to Tomcat internals and is completely invisible to web applications.

So for Java web apps, the setup is identical.